# On company 401k matching. Clarification needed

Tags: united-states, taxes, 401k, retirement-plan

I realized I don't fully understand something. It almost embarrassing to admit.

In 2016 we have 18k max contribution limit for 401k.
**Does this mean that employee can contribute at most 18k or that total contributions made on behalf of employee should not exceed 18k (company match)**

To make is simple, if you make 100k, by contributing 18% you got your limit. But if your company matches 5%, actual contributions will be 18.9k. In the above example, if one wants to maximize benefit should one contribute 18% or less?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The $18K is for employee deferral only. The *total* limit, that includes employer matching and after-tax contributions, is $52K (for 2015). So if you want to maximize the match - you should contribute the whole $18000.

See the details on this [IRS page](https://www.irs.gov/Retirement-Plans/Plan-Participant,-Employee/Retirement-Topics-401k-and-Profit-Sharing-Plan-Contribution-Limits).

Comment: I'd add - If the company matched the first 5% dollar for dollar, it's not 5% of 18K, it's 5% of the $100K, i.e. your 5% of *income* is matched.

Comment: Note that if you make 100 k$, you might come into the HCE range ('Highly Compensated Employee'), where the limit is not 18K, but 10% (which makes only 10k for 100k salary). This is a bitch of a law. Your company must tell you that; if they don't say anything, you are good.

Comment: @Aganju HCE is a relative term, not absolute. Doesn't always mean you only have 10% of the salary if you're above the 100K limit, it depends on how many other employees participate.

Comment: ok, but it is still a bitch when it hits you. Only 10k instead of 17.5$ allowed is just ugly. I hope it doesn't hit others. - P.S.: When I asked HR about it, they offered to reduce my salary. Har, har.