# For the $19.5k limit for 401K contribution in US for 2020, does that include the company matching?

Tags: united-states, 401k, limits, employer-match

I thought it doesn't include the company's matching, or does the $19.5k actually include the part that the company will match?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [On company 401k matching. Clarification needed](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/58212/on-company-401k-matching-clarification-needed)

Comment: yes it does... so if this is true, then if the company matches 100% vs 50%, our final total will be different... but maybe it belongs to another question

Comment: Link explains it, but it's just your contribution, combined contribution limit is $57k

Comment: Not sure I follow your next question, but this might answer that:  https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/123748/does-it-matter-if-one-company-matches-100-of-your-401k-contribution-vs-another/123752#123752

Answer (score 3):

No. For 2020 the $19,500 contribution limit is how much you, the employee, can elect to defer into your 401k from your wages. If you're 50 or older, you can defer an additional $6,500 for a personal total of $26,000.

Your employer can make contributions to your account such that your combined contributions do not exceed $57,000 (or $63,500 if you're 50+.)

The [IRS spells out contribution limits](https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/plan-participant-employee/retirement-topics-401k-and-profit-sharing-plan-contribution-limits). It can get a little complicated if you have multiple plans or employers.